# A moveable QScopedPointer, or a Qt and std cross-compatible unique_pointer

Tags: c++, c++14, pointers, qt

I'm a hobby programmer, so I've never been through a code review before (online or offline). That said, here goes:

### Background

I use Qt extensively but have long wanted `QScopedPointer` to be a moveable type. Since the Qt devs don't plan to implement this, I started trying to implement it myself. This was several years ago. [Pause for laughter]

### Purpose

My goal is to not simply add move semantics to `QScopedPointer`:

- To maintain as much compatibility with the Standard Library as reasonably possible by

  - adding a partial specialization of `std::hash` and `std::swap`,
  - declaring the expected type traits,
  - and implementing all of the public member functions in `std::unique_pointer`.
- To also maintain compatibility with Qt, so that `qe::UniquePointer` acts as a drop-in replacement for `QScopedPointer`.
- Use C++11 and later where appropriate (e.g., `explicit operator bool`). Currently, it compiles with C++14 as a minimum.

### Notes

I kept the Qt-style deleter to allow use of existing deleters for `QScopedPointer`. The lambdas and macros in test.h are my quick-and-dirty GTest stand-in.

### Goals

- I want to make sure the fundamentals are sound. Despite testing, experienced eyeballs are good.
- I don't use Boost and don't have a lot of Standard Library experience. Did I miss any `using` declarations? Is my partial specialization of `std::hash` correctly done?
- I'm least confident about the conversion functions (accepting `qe::UniquePointer<U, Cleanup>`). Have I made any obvious mistakes that may create edge cases?
- Of course, I may have missed something for which the test class simply does not test. Any insight there would be appreciated.

### Code

uniquepointer.h

```
#ifndef QE_CORE_UNIQUEPOINTER_H
#define QE_CORE_UNIQUEPOINTER_H

#include <type_traits>

namespace qe {
namespace detail {

template <class T>
constexpr void assertCompleteType() noexcept
{
    using forced_complete_type = char[sizeof(T) ? 1 : -1];
    (void)sizeof(forced_complete_type);
}

template <class T, class U>
void assertConvertible()
{
    using convertible = char[sizeof(std::is_convertible<T, U>()) ? 1 : -1];
    (void)sizeof(convertible);
}

} // namespace detail

template <typename T>
struct DefaultDeleter
{
    static inline void cleanup(T *pointer)
    {
        if (pointer) {
            qe::detail::assertCompleteType<T>();
            delete pointer;
        }
    }
};

template <class T, class Cleanup = DefaultDeleter<T>>
class UniquePointer
{
public:
    using this_type = UniquePointer<T, Cleanup>;
    using element_type = T;
    using pointer = std::add_pointer_t<T>;
    using const_pointer = std::add_const_t<pointer>;
    using reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>;
    using const_reference = std::add_const_t<reference>;
    using deleter_type = Cleanup;

    inline UniquePointer(pointer p = nullptr) noexcept : d(p) {}
    inline UniquePointer(this_type && other) noexcept : d(other.take()) { }

    template <class U>
    inline UniquePointer(UniquePointer<U, Cleanup> && other) noexcept(std::is_convertible<U, T>())
        : d(other.take())
    {
        qe::detail::assertConvertible<U, T>();
    }

    inline this_type &operator=(this_type &&other)
    {
        if (*this != other)
            reset(other.take());
        return *this;
    }

    template <class U>
    inline this_type &operator=(UniquePointer<U, Cleanup> &&other)
        noexcept(std::is_convertible<U, T>())
    {
        qe::detail::assertConvertible<U, T>();
        if (*this != other)
            reset(other.take());
        return *this;
    }

    UniquePointer(const this_type &) = delete;
    this_type &operator=(const this_type &) = delete;

    inline ~UniquePointer()
    {
        reset(nullptr);
    }

    pointer take() noexcept
    {
        auto oldD = this->d;
        this->d = nullptr;
        return oldD;
    }

    inline void reset(pointer other = nullptr)
    {
        if (this->d == other)
            return;
        auto oldD = this->d;
        if (oldD)
            deleter_type::cleanup(oldD);
        this->d = other;

    }

    inline pointer data() const noexcept            { return this->d; }
    inline pointer get() const noexcept             { return this->d; }
    inline pointer* addressOf() noexcept            { return &(this->d); }
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept         { return !isNull(); }
    inline bool operator!() const noexcept          { return isNull(); }
    inline reference operator*() const noexcept     { return *(this->d); }
    inline pointer operator->() const noexcept      { return this->d; }
    inline bool isNull() const noexcept             { return !(this->d); }
    inline void swap(UniquePointer &other) noexcept { std::swap(this->d, other.d); }

    template <class U>
    void swap(UniquePointer<U, Cleanup> &other)
        noexcept(std::is_convertible<U, T>() && std::is_convertible<T, U>())
    {
        qe::detail::assertConvertible<U, T>();
        qe::detail::assertConvertible<T, U>();
        std::swap(this->d, other.d);
    }

    pointer release() noexcept              { return take(); }

private:
    pointer d;
};

template <class T, class... Args>
inline UniquePointer<T> makeUnique(Args && ...args)
{
    return UniquePointer<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

} //namespace qe

template <class T, class Cleanup>
inline bool operator==(const qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &lhs, const qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &rhs) noexcept
{
    return lhs.data() == rhs.data();
}

template<class T, class Cleanup>
inline bool operator ==(const qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &lhs, std::nullptr_t) noexcept
{
    return lhs.isNull();
}

template<class T, class Cleanup>
inline bool operator ==(std::nullptr_t, const qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &rhs) noexcept
{
    return rhs.isNull();
}

template <class T, class Cleanup>
inline bool operator!=(const qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &lhs, const qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &rhs) noexcept
{
    return lhs.data() != rhs.data();
}

template <class T, class Cleanup>
inline bool operator !=(const qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &lhs, std::nullptr_t) noexcept
{
    return !lhs.data();
}

template <class T, class Cleanup>
inline bool operator !=(std::nullptr_t, const qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &rhs) noexcept
{
    return !rhs.data();
}

namespace std {
template <class T, class Cleanup>
inline void swap(qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &lhs, qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup> &rhs) noexcept
{
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}

template <class T, class Cleanup>
struct hash<qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup>>
{
    using argument_type = qe::UniquePointer<T, Cleanup>;
    using result_type = std::size_t;
    inline result_type operator()(const argument_type & p) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<T *>{}(p.data());
    }
};
} //namespace std

#endif //QE_CORE_UNIQUEPOINTER_H
```

test.h

```
#ifndef QE_TEST_TEST_H
#define QE_TEST_TEST_H

#include <assert.h>

auto equal_check = [](auto && lhs, auto && rhs) -> bool
{
    return (lhs == rhs) && (rhs == lhs);
};

auto not_equal_check = [](auto && lhs, auto && rhs) -> bool
{
    return (lhs != rhs);
};

auto less_than_check = [](auto && lhs, auto && rhs) -> bool
{
    return (lhs < rhs);
};

auto less_than_or_equal_check = [](auto && lhs, auto && rhs) -> bool
{
    return (lhs <= rhs);
};

auto greater_than_check = [](auto && lhs, auto && rhs) -> bool
{
    return (lhs > rhs);
};

auto greater_than_or_equal_check = [](auto && lhs, auto && rhs) -> bool
{
    return (lhs >= rhs);
};

auto implicit_true_check = [](auto && lhs) -> bool
{
    return lhs ? true : false;
};

auto implicit_false_check = [](auto && lhs) -> bool
{
    return lhs ? false : true;
};

#define EXPECT_EQ(x, y) assert(equal_check(x, y))
#define EXPECT_NE(x, y) assert(not_equal_check(x, y))
#define EXPECT_LT(x, y) assert(less_than_check(x, y))
#define EXPECT_LE(x, y) assert(less_than_or_equal_check(x, y))
#define EXPECT_GT(x, y) assert(greater_than_check(x, y))
#define EXPECT_GE(x, y) assert(greater_than_or_equal_check(x, y))
#define EXPECT_TRUE(x)  assert(implicit_true_check(x))
#define EXPECT_FALSE(x) assert(implicit_false_check(x))

#endif // QE_TEST_TEST_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "uniquepointer.h"
#include "test.h"

using namespace qe;

struct Struct1
{
    explicit Struct1(int aVal)
        : value(aVal)
    {
        instances++;
    }

    Struct1(const Struct1 &) = default;
    Struct1(Struct1 &&) = default;

    ~Struct1()
    {
        instances--;
    }

    Struct1 &operator =(const Struct1 &) = default;
    Struct1 &operator =(Struct1 &&) = default;

    void incr()
    {
        value++;
    }

    void decr()
    {
        value--;
    }

    int value = 0;
    static int instances;
};

int Struct1::instances = 0;

struct Struct2 : public Struct1
{
    explicit Struct2(const int aVal)
        : Struct1(aVal)
    {

    }
};


struct Struct3 : public Struct1
{
    Struct3(const Struct2 &other)
        : Struct1(other.value)
    {
    }
    Struct3(const Struct2 &&other)
        : Struct1(other.value)
    {
    }
    Struct3 operator=(const Struct2 &other)
    {
        Struct3 ret(other);
        return ret;

    }

    Struct3 operator=(Struct2 &&other)
    {
        Struct3 ret(other);
        other.~Struct2();
        return ret;
    }
};

struct unique_pointer_test
{

    static void run()
    {
        empty_pointer_test();
        basic_pointer_test();
        reset_pointer_test();
        compare_pointer_test();
        swap_pointer_test();
        std_container_test();
    }

    static void empty_pointer_test()
    {
        // Create an empty (ie. nullptr) UniquePointer
        UniquePointer<Struct2> xPtr = nullptr;

        EXPECT_FALSE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_EQ(nullptr, xPtr.get());

        // Reset to nullptr (ie. do nothing)
        xPtr.reset();

        EXPECT_FALSE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_EQ(nullptr,  xPtr.get());
    }

    static void basic_pointer_test()
    {
        {
            // Create a UniquePointer
            UniquePointer<Struct2> xPtr(new Struct2(123));

            EXPECT_TRUE(xPtr);
            EXPECT_NE(nullptr, xPtr.get());

            if (xPtr)
            {
                EXPECT_EQ(123,  xPtr->value);
                EXPECT_EQ(1,    xPtr->instances);
                EXPECT_EQ(1,    Struct1::instances);

                // call a function
                xPtr->incr();
                EXPECT_EQ(124,  xPtr->value);
                (*xPtr).incr();
                EXPECT_EQ(125,  (*xPtr).value);
                xPtr->decr();
                xPtr->decr();

                // Copy construct the UniquePointer, transferring ownership
                UniquePointer<Struct2> yPtr(std::move(xPtr));
                xPtr.reset();

                EXPECT_NE(xPtr, yPtr);
                EXPECT_FALSE(xPtr);
                EXPECT_EQ(nullptr,  xPtr.get());
                EXPECT_TRUE(yPtr);
                EXPECT_NE(nullptr,  yPtr.get());
                EXPECT_EQ(123,   yPtr->value);
                EXPECT_EQ(1,     Struct1::instances);

                if (yPtr)
                {
                    UniquePointer<Struct2> zPtr = std::move(yPtr);
                    yPtr.reset();

                    EXPECT_NE(yPtr,  zPtr);
                    EXPECT_FALSE(yPtr);
                    EXPECT_EQ(nullptr, yPtr.get());
                    EXPECT_TRUE(zPtr);
                    EXPECT_NE(nullptr,  zPtr.get());
                    EXPECT_EQ(123,   zPtr->value);
                    EXPECT_EQ(1,     Struct1::instances);
                }

                EXPECT_FALSE(xPtr);
                EXPECT_EQ(nullptr, xPtr.get());
                EXPECT_FALSE(yPtr);
                EXPECT_EQ(nullptr, yPtr.get());
                EXPECT_EQ(0, Struct1::instances);
            }
            else
            {
                assert(false); //"bool cast operator error"
            }

            EXPECT_FALSE(xPtr);
            EXPECT_EQ(nullptr, xPtr.get());
            EXPECT_EQ(0, Struct1::instances);
        }

        EXPECT_EQ(0, Struct1::instances);
    }

    static void reset_pointer_test()
    {
        // Create an empty (ie. nullptr) UniquePointer
        UniquePointer<Struct2> xPtr;

        // Reset it with a new pointer
        xPtr.reset(new Struct2(123));

        EXPECT_TRUE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr, xPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(123,  xPtr->value);
        EXPECT_EQ(1,    Struct1::instances);
        Struct2* pX  = xPtr.get();

        // Reset it with another new pointer
        xPtr.reset(new Struct2(234));

        EXPECT_TRUE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr, xPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(234,  xPtr->value);
        EXPECT_EQ(1,    Struct1::instances);
        EXPECT_NE(pX,   xPtr.get());

        // Move-construct a new UniquePointer to the same object, transferring ownership
        UniquePointer<Struct2> yPtr = std::move(xPtr);
        xPtr.reset();

        EXPECT_NE(xPtr, yPtr);
        EXPECT_FALSE( xPtr);
        EXPECT_EQ(nullptr,  xPtr.get());
        EXPECT_TRUE( yPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr,  yPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(234,   yPtr->value);
        EXPECT_EQ(1,     Struct1::instances);

        // Reset to nullptr
        yPtr.reset();

        EXPECT_EQ(nullptr,  yPtr.get());
        EXPECT_FALSE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_EQ(nullptr,  xPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(0, Struct1::instances);
    }

    static void compare_pointer_test()
    {
        // Create a UniquePointer
        UniquePointer<Struct2> xPtr(new Struct2(123));

        EXPECT_TRUE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr, xPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(123,xPtr->value);
        EXPECT_EQ(1, Struct1::instances);
        Struct2* pX = xPtr.get();

        // Create another UniquePointer
        UniquePointer<Struct2> yPtr(new Struct2(234));

        EXPECT_TRUE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr, xPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(123,xPtr->value);
        EXPECT_EQ(2, Struct1::instances);

        EXPECT_TRUE(yPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr, yPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(234, yPtr->value);
        Struct2* pY = yPtr.get();


        EXPECT_NE(xPtr, yPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(pY->value, pX->value);
    }

    static void swap_pointer_test()
    {
        // Create a UniquePointer
        UniquePointer<Struct2> xPtr(new Struct2(123));

        EXPECT_TRUE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr, xPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(123,xPtr->value);
        EXPECT_EQ(1, Struct1::instances);

        // Create another UniquePointer
        UniquePointer<Struct2> yPtr(new Struct2(234));

        EXPECT_TRUE(yPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr, yPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(234, yPtr->value);
        EXPECT_EQ(2, Struct1::instances);

        EXPECT_LT(xPtr->value, yPtr->value);
        xPtr.swap(yPtr);
        EXPECT_GT(xPtr->value, yPtr->value);
        EXPECT_TRUE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_TRUE(yPtr);
    }

    static void std_container_test()
    {
        // Create a shared_ptr
        UniquePointer<Struct2> xPtr(new Struct2(123));

        EXPECT_TRUE(xPtr);
        EXPECT_NE(nullptr, xPtr.get());
        EXPECT_EQ(123, xPtr->value);
        EXPECT_EQ(1, Struct1::instances);
        Struct2* pX = xPtr.get();

        {
            std::vector<UniquePointer<Struct2> > PtrList;

            // Move-it inside a container, transferring ownership
            PtrList.push_back(std::move(xPtr));

            EXPECT_FALSE(xPtr);
            EXPECT_TRUE( PtrList.back());
            EXPECT_EQ(pX,PtrList.back().get());
            EXPECT_EQ(1, Struct1::instances);

        } // Destructor of the vector releases the last pointer thus destroying the object

        EXPECT_EQ(0, Struct1::instances);
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)(argc);
    (void)(argv);

    unique_pointer_test::run();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: here's the code on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aNLMeQqtgduf3ioS)

Edit 2: Removed need for C++17. Compiles with C++14.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, and congratulations on writing a well-written question on your first go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, how about a radical idea:

Just use `std::unique_ptr`, the only extra-capability yours has is `.addressOf()`. Yes, you might have to write replacements for `QScopedPointerPodDeleter` and `QScopedPointerDeleteLater` if you use either, but that isn't hard:

```
struct FreeDeleter {
    static void operator()(void* p) noexcept { free(p); }
};
struct DeleteLater {
    template <class T>
    static void operator()(T* p) noexcept { p->deleteLater(); }
};
```

Anyway, now let's criticise how you wrote your own one:

1. [`static_assert` is the tool of choice for causing compile-time-errors if something doesn't check out at compile-time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert). Learn to use and love it.
2. You can safely [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) or [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free) a null-pointer. It's defined to do nothing.
3. Inside the class-definition and out-of-line member-function-definition-bodies, you can use the [injected name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) `UniquePointer` to refer to refer to the class. No need to mention the template-parameters unless you want some unrelated class from the same template.
4. Decorating an in-class-definition with `inline` is [absolutely pointless](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).
5. I'm not sure why you put that expression into the noexcept-specification of the templated ctor. You should either use it for SFINAE, or a `static_assert`, but this makes no sense at all. I prefer the first:

   ```
   template <class U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U, T>()>::type>
   UniquePointer(UniquePointer<U, Cleanup> && other) noexcept
   : d(other.take()) {}
   ```
6. I suggest doing minimal work when move-assigning: Simply swap.
7. You know, simply delegating to what you already have written would simplify your templated move-assignment-operator:

   ```
   template <class U>
   auto operator=(UniquePointer<U, Cleanup>&& other) noexcept
   -> decltype((*this = UniquePointer(other))) // The extra-parens are critical
   { return (*this = UniquePointer(other)); }
   ```
8. [Copy-ctor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and [copy-assignment-operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) are already implicitly deleted.
9. I wonder why you don't take advantage of the default-argument to `.reset()` in the dtor.
10. There is something really disturbing going on when you try to make your smart-pointer responsible for what it already is responsible for. It might make sense to assert that doesn't happen, but are you *really* sure that should silently do nothing?
11. Also in `.reset()`, I got to wondering whether the deleter is responsible for handling null-pointers, or your smart-pointer, or both? You seem to really like testing for null-pointers everywhere, anyway the compiler should be able to deduplicate the code just fine.
12. Your templated `.swap()`  is utterly useless. Again, the expression which should be used for SFINAE is in the `noexcept`-specification, and you force a compile-time-error later when the body gets compiled instead, unless `U` is `T`. In that case though, the non-templated version claims precedence.
13. Write `operator==` and `operator!=` differently, and they will be far more comprehensive and useful:

    ```
    template <class T, class D, class U>
    constexpr auto operator==(const UniquePointer<T, D>& a, const U& b) noexcept
    -> decltype(b == a.d)
    { return b == a.d; }
    template <class T, class D, class U>
    constexpr auto operator==(const U& a, const UniquePointer<T, D>& b) noexcept
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<U>() || std::is_null_pointer<U>(), decltype(a == b.d)>
    { return a == b.d; }
    ```

    That also covers comparing with raw pointers, possible down-casting, and smart-pointers following the same pattern.
14. You should not put your own `swap()` in `::std`. Even though it probably works, it's not allowed. Either [rely on ADL to pick it up from the same namespace as your type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), or depend on `std::swap()` (which should be good enough anyway).

Comment: re #6:  the generic `std::swap` will use the class’s move assignment and move constructor, so do it the other way around:  implement assignment, and let the library auto-generate `swap`.

Comment: a note on obsessively checking for null: use [`gsl::not_null`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#gslview-views) and the compiler only inserts a check *once*, where needed.

Comment: Regarding 0: why I don't use `unique_ptr`? Because this is a hobby for me. I'm learning the motivations by studying implementations and trying my own hand at it. I have no professional aspirations. =) Oh, and I also originally started this before I had access to a C++11 compiler.

Comment: @JonHarper: He has `.swap()` already. Also, he could swap the only member.

Comment: Re #14: Partial specializations of `std` templates [are allowed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std): "It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited." and "It is undefined behavior to declare a full specialization of any member function template of a standard library class or class template".

Comment: Edit to the above: I meant to say *function* templates can be partially specialized.

Comment: @JonHarper Function templates cannot be partially specialized at all.

Comment: Woah. Just looked that up. My ignorance is showing; apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Congrats, and good luck with your endeavors.

---

```
template <class T>
constexpr void assertCompleteType() noexcept
{
    using forced_complete_type = char[sizeof(T) ? 1 : -1];
    (void)sizeof(forced_complete_type);
}
```

Huh?  A constexpr that doesn’t return a value, and an expression that does nothing?

I think you want to use `static_assert`, not a trick to cause an error in template instantiation.

```
static_assert (sizeof(T) > 0);
static_assert (std::is_convertible_v<T,U>);
```

---

```
inline UniquePointer(pointer p = nullptr) noexcept : d(p) {}
inline UniquePointer(this_type && other) noexcept : d(other.take()) { }
```

You don’t have to use `inline` when putting the body of the function inside the class.

Use the usual names for things:  `take` should be `release`

Use `=delete` on the copy constructor and assignment operator, to prevent them from being automatically generated.  Do provide a move assignment operator.

---

```
template <class U>
inline this_type &operator=(UniquePointer<U, Cleanup> &&other)
    noexcept(std::is_convertible<U, T>())
{
    qe::detail::assertConvertible<U, T>();
    if (*this != other)
        reset(other.take());
    return *this;
}
```

The `is_convertible` in the `noexcept` doesn’t make sense.  It is non-throwing if what you do in the body will never throw.  If this is a trick to get SFINAE tucked away, it will not work.  Likewise, the `assertConvertible` does not belong in the body at all!  You want this form of `operator=` to only match overloading **if** the conversion is possible.

That is, use `std::enable_if`, as an extra dummy template parameter.

Meanwhile, it doesn’t make sense to assign an `int*` to a `long*` without any kind of conversion going on.  You want to check conversion ability on the pointers, not on the types being pointed to!

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

```
    auto oldD = this->d;
    this->d = nullptr;
```

Don’t use `this->` for normal member access.

In this function, you could just write `return std::exchange (d, nullptr);`. See [CPPreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) — you mentioned needing to get to know the libraries better; this is a good resource to keep at hand.

Comment: Thank you for your review!
1. The constexpr is definitely a late-night mishap. However, the code itself (without `constexpr`) *ought* to cause a template instantiation error if an incomplete type is provided. It's used immediately before `Cleanup` is called. Is static_assert still the better method?

2. The use of `take()` along with `release()` is intended for Qt compatibility. =)

3. I had a bad feeling about the conversion code. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: I just realized that because the deleter is not stored, swapping with a convertible type is out anyway. I could test for a virtual destructor, though...

Comment: `static_assert` is the right way to cause a compile error on purpose if some condition is not met. However, you should use`enable_if` to prevent such uses in the first place.

Comment: By the way, the `assertCompleteType` function (sans `constexpr`) is an idiom used to allow forward-declared types to be stored as pointers. It's generalized from Qt's `QScopedPointerDeleter`. I adapted it to remove dependency on Qt for this review.

Comment: Forward-declared types can indeed be used for pointers.  What good is choking if the type is incomplete *instead*?  Hmm, you want to make sure it is not incomplete when you `delete` it?  Anyway, `static_assert`, as of C++11, obsoletes tricks for achieving the same end.

Answer (score 0):

## comparison operators

You don’t need so many forms of the comparison operators.

First of all, a single template for `!=` will reverse the sense of any `==` that you have, so don’t write all of them twice.

Second, don’t write special forms for `nullptr`.  You are discouraged from writing explicit tests against `nullptr` and instead use the contextual conversion to `bool` and `operator!`.  In fact, before C++11 you could not have special forms for this.

If you have another value that is null, the general form will be used; so, it has to handle the null case.

You *can* however provide a non-explicit constructor that converts `nullptr` to the smart pointer type.

Comment: Why didn't you just add that to your previously posted review?

Comment: @Deduplicator I thought the OP might not see it at the end of a long answer he already read.  There’s no notification to the OP for edits.

Comment: But for comments, which you can leave in addition.